Rails collection select not setting default value
I'm having a problem when trying to set selected value on rails collection_select. It works with .all, but don't if has where clause. Ex:
this works perfectly:
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, MaProduct.all, :id, :name, { selected: (@user.product_id) }, class: 'form-control' %>

But when add where clause, don't. Ex:
<%= f.collection_select :product_id, MaProduct.where(language_id: 1), :id, :name, { selected: (@user.product_id) }, class: 'form-control' %>


Are you sure that you are passing valid id in selected attribute?
Because you are passing MaProduct.where(), which will return certain records where it may not have @user.product_id. Could you please verify it again.

Is it possible that the value in @user.product_id is not included in the products returned by MaProduct.where(language_id: 1) ?.
